# Evict image from cache flutter not working

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to remove a single image entry from the flutter cache using the `evict()` method from  the `NetworkImage` class and it keeps failing.

Here how I do the evict:

```
final NetworkImage provider = NetworkImage(url);
try {
   bool res = await provider.evict();
   print("eviction result : $res");
} catch (error) {
   print(error.toString());
}
```

And how my image is rendered:

```
CircleAvatar(
      radius: 80,
      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(url))),
```

This print `flutter: eviction result : false` in the console and the image cache is not removed. Any idea of what i'm missing ?

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? Please check if you can reproduce with `master` channel.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm using the stable channel `Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.14 18A391, locale en-AU)`

Comment: Try `master` or `dev` channel. As far as I remember there was a fix not too long ago and `stable` is from end of November.